# SQL matching and combining search in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sql db ( one table ) with two fields `RDN` and `Rprob`. I want to report what records from `RDN` match a certain record from `Rprob` and I want it to search for all the 3400 record I have.

Data example:

[image]

It should return something like : `aa` found on 1,2,3 `bb` found only on 1 and `cc` only on 2

Comment: Hi @WHB,  I went ahead and gave an answer to your question based on my best guess,  Please look here for a great tutorial on asking for assistance with SQL on this or any other forum: http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/.  You are more likely to have your question answered if it is well formed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `XML PATH` and `STUFF`.  The below query will group and concatenate distinct occurences of RDN by RProb.

```
declare @test table (
rdn int,
rprob varchar(2)
);

insert into @test
values
(1, 'aa'),
(1, 'aa'),
(1, 'bb'),
(2, 'aa'),
(2, 'cc')


select  rprob + ' found in: ' + 
        stuff((
            select distinct ', ' +  cast(rdn as varchar(max))
            from @test t
            where r.rprob = t.rprob 
            for xml path(''),type).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)'),1,2,'') as valz 
from @test r
group by r.rprob
```

**Returns:**

```
FoundIn
aa found in: 1, 2
bb found in: 1
cc found in: 2
```

Learn more about `FOR XML PATH` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx

And `STUFF` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx

`STRING_AGG` is new in vNext and Azure SQL and definitely worth looking at if you can leverage it:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790580.aspx

Comment: Thanks looks helpful, can we do a simple update to make it check in a current DB with almost 3000 record, i mean to change ur code ( the block of insert into value) and make it search on RESULT table or make auto insert value statement to do the wok ?

Comment: Yes, you can modify this query to point to your actual table.  Replace references to `from @test` with your `from yourtable`.  Insert is for demonstration in this example.

Comment: Thanks Dear sounds like it's works perfect, would you please check my original data and the obtained results for any advises, also there is a comments on the attached images if you can help on !!

Comment: i don't know why, but i couldn't upload the 2 images that i want to show it to u

Comment: for xml path(''),type).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)'),1,2,'')  can i know what is the meaning of those values ? i mean the numbers 1, and 1,2